# How do I assign an integer value to a character?

Tags: java, char, integer, stack

for example, if I want to say that c=4 and d=4, then c*d=16? I'm reading both c and d values from input. my sample test case is: c = 45 d = 45. I've got it store the c into a variable called charVal and 45 is stored into value. When I insert statement like, charVal=value, it gives me errors saying incompatible types. how would I do that?

Comment: Why do you want to store it in a char? Why can't int or byte? Any specific reason?

Comment: @DanielNugent it gives me a"_" an output.

Comment: It's actually `-`, and that's expected for `45`. Take a look at the ASCII table: http://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a map.

> The java.util.Map interface represents a mapping between a key and a value.

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("c", 4);
    map.put("d", 4);
    System.out.println(map.get("c") + map.get("d"));
```

Returns

```
8
```

Comment: it gives an unexpected type error when I try that.

Comment: sorry, int should be Integer

Comment: @DexterMorgan It's good to know though, you can't use a primitive (int), in a Generic. The generic must derive from java.lang.Object. Integer does, but int is a primitive and it doesnt.

Comment: it gives me an out put a dash, "-". I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I just ran it, and it gives me 8. You must have something else going wrong.

Comment: Thanks! I left out the .get statement. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use 2D arrays where you use row[0] column[0] to store characters and row[0] column[1] to store integers or vice versa and for any character you go ahead take its respective column value and multiply it.

And finally convert your 2D String array to Int using following method:

```
int y = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I'm already doing that converting the input string into the an integer. My question is how do I assign a value to a char? for example, if I have C as char, how do I say c=4, when I do c*c, i should get 16?